# SQL to select with specific length of results sum criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I did search a lot but couldn’t find the way to write this sql. 
I have a mysql db with pieces of texts with various lengths. I want to select 10 pieces  of texts and I want that the sum of the lengths of those 10 pieces  are between some length or characters length criteria. 
Is it possible?
Sub querying maybe?

Or like this:

```
SELECT text 
FROM tablename AS result 
WHERE CHAR _LENGHT (result) BETWEEN min AND max
ORDER BY RAND ( ) LIMIT 10
```

This one does not work due to the aliase not being accepted into the CHAR_LENGTH.

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: What if all pieces of text are so longer that 10 pieces will either never make up the total length or that 10 pieces will be much bigger that the desired maximum length.

Comment: My idea is to specify a range for the length, instead of a spedific value.

Answer (score 2):

This is *possible* in SQL, but neither simple nor recommended.  Basically, you need to do 10 joins.

Let me give you an example with three, assuming you want no dupicates:

```
select t1.text, t2.text, t3.text
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.text < t2.text
     t t3
     on t2.text < t3.text
where length(t1.text) + length(t2.text) + length(t3.text) = ?
```

The problem is that this considers all possibilities -- basically doing a giant Cartesian product.  Even with a few dozen rows in the table, the query will probably not finish with 10 tables.

Comment: Tks for the answer. It looks like a really messy idea indeed.

Answer (score 0):

This is just the same a Gordon
I thought I might be able to make a recursive CTE work but could not

```
declare @len table (iden int IDENTITY(1,1) primary key, tlen int);
insert into @len(tlen) values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (12), (11), (10), (9), (8), (7);
--select * from @len order by iden;

select l1.tlen, l2.tlen, l3.tlen
from @len l1 
join @len l2
  on l2.tlen > l1.tlen  
join @len l3
  on l3.tlen > l2.tlen  
where l1.tlen + l2.tlen + l3.tlen = 15 
order by l1.tlen, l2.tlen, l3.tlen;
```